# FBML Facebook Landing page

Tags: facebook-fbml

I'm wondering if I create a new tab on a Facebook page using FBML, how do I make this tab appear first as a landing page (rather than the wall) if the user has not 'liked' the Facebook page first?

Answer (score 1):

1. Click "Edit Page" underneath the profile picture when viewing your Page.
2. Select "Manage Permissions" from the left sidebar.
3. You will see an option called "Default Landing Tab." From there, you can select which tab your Page will default to. Be sure to save your changes to ensure that this is what people will see when they visit your Page for the first time.

(source: http://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=14899)